# Possible to transport audio data within the Bluetooth HID specification?

Tags: bluetooth, hid

I have a device that contains joysticks and a microphone. What would be the best Bluetooth profile to carry this data over. Are both kinds of data supported by HID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, HID will not support voice.  You can use HID for the joystick.  If the microphone is for voice, you would use HFP (hands free profile).

Comment: Can both protocols be supported on a single device at the same time to allow simultaneous communication of both types of data?

Comment: @user48956 , I have the same question. can one bluetooth device connect using multiple profiles for simultaneous use ? HID and HFP. did you ever find an answer to this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, if you are prepared enough to reinvent the wheel on both the host and the device.

You should be able to fit whatever you want in the data payload (for an example, you can see [here](https://habr.com/en/post/302356/) and [here](https://sensepost.com/blog/2020/dual-pod-shock-emotional-abuse-of-a-dualshock/) how Sony embedded SBC from A2DP inside HID)

I'm not really sure on whether this road is either incredibly shrewd, or incredibly dim.